# How to optimize img file inside in PHP (Laravel 5.2)

Tags: php, image, laravel, optimization, compression

We always getting warning for "no img (png/jpeg/jpg) file compressed" notice on site audit.

[Kantipath.com](https://www.kantipath.com) is running news site uploading 50-60 page per day with verious img file.

We have more than 10K img files on site folder which is almost impossible to compress and upload one by one

1. Is there any way to compress these pre loaded img(png/jpeg/jpg) files  2
2. Is there any option for future uploads, which automatically compressed/optimized?

Can someone share idea?

Our frameworks are in Laravel 5.2

[KantipathNews](http://kantipath.com)

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870129/compress-jpeg-on-server-with-php

Comment: Have a look at Intervention: http://image.intervention.io/

Comment: You could use `optipng` and `jpegtran` to losslessly optimize your existing images, and then use one of the many "image-optimizer" PHP classes for your future image uploads. Try one of those and get back if problems :)

Comment: Thanks for help.@apokryfos @Danny H