# How to compress images for better web response time?

Tags: php, apache, drupal

I have a political website (on LAMP stack), which is displaying images hosted on another site. Is there away for me to compress the image at apache level for better web response time?

Answer (score 0):

Ive used ImageMagick successfully for to manipulate file size.

https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Take a look at his too...

http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

And kind of a duplicate...

[Compress jpeg on server with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870129/compress-jpeg-on-server-with-php)